How to set PageIndex in 'react-data-table-component'?
I have stored currentPageIndex of 'react-data-table-component' using onChangePage={handlePageChange} and store the pageIndex in context.
I want to retain the page index in my table when i come back to the list page.
I get my savedpageIndex from context.
But I can't pass the pageIndex to 'react-data-table-component'. It always goes back to the first page!.
This below assignment not working as expected 'currentPage={10}'.
<DataTable
            title={<THeader />}                        
            columns={columns}
            data={tableData}
            actions={actionComponentMemo}
            customStyles={customTableStyles}
            pagination
            **currentPage={10}**
            onChangePage={handlePageChange}
            fixedHeader
            fixedHeaderScrollHeight="440px" //remove this if you dont need table scroll
            selectableRows
            selectableRowsHighlight
            selectableRowsRadio="checkbox"
            pointerOnHover
            className=" border z-10"
            contextActions={contextActions}
            onSelectedRowsChange={handleRowSelected}
            clearSelectedRows={toggleCleared}  
            onRowClicked={(row)=> navigate(`/consumer-list/${row.id}`)}
          />


Thank you all!. But I found the answer myself.
'react-data-table-component' have this option by default.
paginationDefaultPage={savedPageIndex}

Instead of using 'currentPage={yourSavedPageIndex}',I used the above assignment. And it works as expected.
<DataTable
            title={<THeader />}                        
            columns={columns}
            data={tableData}            
            pagination
            paginationDefaultPage={yourSavedPageIndex}
            onChangePage={handlePageChange}
            ..........
            ....otheroptions
          />

